# How to use single jQuery ajax post with multiple functions inputting data

Tags: jquery

I am quite new to jQuery and having trouble with below code. It gets values from 3 sets of checkboxes and uses the values for each in the ajax post.

The ajax post is identical each time. It all works perfectly, but obviously not coded well.

How can I just have the ajax post once but have the 3 functions providing data. Any help apppreciated very much. Spent ages trying.

```
$('.filters-price input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var d1x = 'price';

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'Filter.php',
        data:'id='+d1x,
        success:function(html){
            $('#myDiv').replaceWith(html);
        }
    });
});

$('.filters-duration input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var d1x = 'duration';

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'Filter.php',
        data:'id='+d1x,
        success:function(html){
            $('#myDiv').replaceWith(html);
        }
    });
});

$('.filters-rating input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var d1x = 'rating';

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'Filter.php',
        data:'id='+d1x,
        success:function(html){
            $('#myDiv').replaceWith(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Get the `.filters-*` class from `this`, get the part after the hyphen, pass that string to the `$.ajax()` call (which is wrapped in a function with a fitting name)

Comment: If the code works, and you'd like a review of all aspects of the code, this question *might* be on topic on [codereview.se], but please read their help center first before asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the approach. First, give all of the `filters-*` elements the same (additional) class (`filters` in this example) and add a `data-` attribute with the `dlx` value you need to pass to your service (`data-filter-dlx` in this example).

Then all you need is a single function:

```
$('.filters input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
  var dlx = $(this).attr('data-filter-dlx');

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'Filter.php',
    data:'id='+d1x,             
    success:function(html){     
      ('#myDiv').replaceWith(html);
    }
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$('.filters-price input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var d1x = 'price';

    call_ajax(d1x);
});

$('.filters-duration input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var d1x = 'duration';

    call_ajax(d1x);
});

$('.filters-rating input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var d1x = 'rating';
    call_ajax(d1x);
});

// Create a function
function call_ajax(data_id){
   $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'Filter.php',
        data:'id='+data_id,
        success:function(html){
            $('#myDiv').replaceWith(html);
        }
    });
}
```